# Flutter - Navigate to home page if response status 200

Tags: flutter

How inside function put Navigator is it possible? I need redirect from login to home page if status code = 200.
When try below code get Undefined name 'context'

```
signIn(String username, password) async {

  //////

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if(jsonResponse != null) {

      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage');
    }
  }
}
```

when put Navigator here work but if enter wrong username and password again redirect to HomePage

```
onPressed: () {
  signIn(username.text, password.text);
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage');
},
```

Comment: Can't you pass your context to your function ? Navigator is not the issue, its the context you are missing

Comment: @Wapazz  I'm updated my question, what is your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions here:

First you can provide the context as parameter:

```
signIn(String username, password, context) async {

  //////

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if(jsonResponse != null) {

      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage');
    }
  }
}
```

Second option is to delegate the redirection by just using the responde code:

```
onPressed: () {
  int code = await signIn(username.text, password.text);
  if (code == 200)
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage');
  else
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Login');
},


...

int signIn(String username, password) async {

  //////

  return response.statusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `signIn` function into onPress of Button in the build function

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
            UsernameTextField()
            PasswordTextField()
            SignInButton(
                onTap: () {
                    await signIn(username, password, contex);
                  },
                )
         ]
    )

}

signIn(String username, String password, BuildContext context) async {
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if(jsonResponse != null) {

      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage');
    }
  }
}
```